# Check_MK: Custom User Notification goes to all users not to the one in Contact Groups

Tags: monitoring, check-mk, sms, notification

I would like to kindly ask for some advice.

I have configuration that looks like this:

Users are in Contact Groups.
In Host Folders I have permissions to Contact Groups. And Hosts inherits this setting from folders

That works fine for Global Notification Rules
But I Have SMS notifications with different time periods defined.

So in every user with sms notification, I’ve created new custom notification rule for user

It works, and sends sms in proper time periods.

Problem is that it now send notifications for all hosts not for the one that should be send.
So it sends sms messages for users even if they are not in Contact Groups of that server.

And I’m stuck. Can someone try to help me?

In Global Notification Rules there is option “Restrict to Contact Groups” that should be ok for me, but it’s not available in custom user Rules. There is option “Match Contact Groups” instead but it doesn’t work like this .

Answer (score 0):

OK. Solved.
This is very stupid but to make it work I had to add Match Contact and select user that I'm editing.
Stupid and very unintuitive but works.